# Implementing a Hilbert-like space-filling-curve conversion in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, bitwise, rcpp

I have written a series of functions that are designed to create a space-filling curve (similar to a Hilbert Curve) that is intended for symmetric matrices (as opposed to a square region).

I plan to ultimately use the function in `R`, but decided to write it in `c++` for the sake of speed.

Also, you may notice that I am using 64 bit integers.  This is because I am converting 2d coordinates that can be in the million, so the 1d vector will be extremely long and will need very large integers to index it.

Also, if you see anywhere I make save time by implementing bitwise operations, please point them out.

---

````
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;

# include <bitset>
# include <cstdint>
# include <ctime>
# include <iomanip>
# include <iostream>

using namespace std;

# include "hilbert_curve_copy.hpp"

//****************************************************************************80
// [[Rcpp::export]]
void rot ( int n, uint64_t &x, uint64_t &y, int rx, int ry ) 
//****************************************************************************80
  //
  //  Purpose:
  //
  //    ROT rotates and flips a quadrant appropriately
  //
  //  Modified:
  //
  //    24 December 2015
  //
  //  Parameters:
  //
  //    Input, int N, the length of a side of the square.  N must be a power of 2.
  //
  //    Input/output, int &X, &Y, the input and output coordinates of a point.
  //
  //    Input, int RX, RY, the region (left/right  -- upper/lower) 
  //
{
  int t;
  // 0  3         0--1  14-15     Only rotate and/or flip if in the upper y quadrant (ry == 1).
  // |  |            |  |         
  // 1--2   -->   3--2  13-12     Reflect vertically and horizontally BEFORE swapping x and y
  //              |        |      only for the upper left side (rx == 0 and ry == 1)
  //              4  7--8  11
  //              |  |  |  |
  //              5--6  9--10
  if ( ry == 1 )
  {
    //
    //  Reflect horizonally AND veritcally
    //
    if ( rx == 0 )
    {
      x = n - 1 - x;
      y = n - 1 - y;
    }
    //
    //  Flip (i.e. reflect accross the line y = x, i.e. swap x and y)
    //
    t = x;
    x = y;
    y = t;
  }
  return;
}

//****************************************************************************80
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector makeInt64(std::vector<int64_t> v) {
  size_t len = v.size();
  Rcpp::NumericVector n(len);         // storage vehicle we return them in

  // transfers values 'keeping bits' but changing type
  // using reinterpret_cast would get us a warning
  std::memcpy(&(n[0]), &(v[0]), len * sizeof(int64_t));

  n.attr("class") = "integer64";
  return n;
}


//****************************************************************************80
// [[Rcpp::export]]
uint64_t i4_power ( int i, int j )
//****************************************************************************80
//
//  Purpose:
//
//    I4_POWER returns the value of I^J.
//
//  Licensing:
//
//    This code is distributed under the GNU LGPL license.
//
//  Modified:
//
//    01 April 2004
//
//  Author:
//
//    John Burkardt
//
//  Parameters:
//
//    Input, int I, J, the base and the power.  J should be nonnegative.
//
//    Output, int I4_POWER, the value of I^J.
//
{
  int k;
  uint64_t value;

  if ( j < 0 )
  {
    if ( i == 1 )
    {
      value = 1;
    }
    else if ( i == 0 )
    {
      cerr << "\n";
      cerr << "I4_POWER - Fatal error!\n";
      cerr << "  I^J requested, with I = 0 and J negative.\n";
      exit ( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
      value = 0;
    }
  }
  else if ( j == 0 )
  {
    if ( i == 0 )
    {
      cerr << "\n";
      cerr << "I4_POWER - Fatal error!\n";
      cerr << "  I^J requested, with I = 0 and J = 0.\n";
      exit ( 1 );
    }
    else
    {
      value = 1;
    }
  }
  else if ( j == 1 )
  {
    value = i;
  }
  else
  {
    value = 1;
    for ( k = 1; k <= j; k++ )
    {
      value = value * i;
    }
  }
  return value;
}


//****************************************************************************80
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::NumericVector xy2d ( int m, uint64_t x, uint64_t y )
//****************************************************************************80
{
  const uint64_t n = i4_power ( 2, m );

  if ( x > n - 1 || y > n - 1) {
    throw std::range_error("Neither x nor y may be larger than (2^m - 1)\n");
  }

  uint64_t d = 0;
  int state = 0;
  for ( uint64_t s = n / 2; s > 0; s = s / 2 )
  {
    //  rx = x region (right = 1, left equals 0) 
    //  ry = y region (top = 1, bottom = 0)
    int rx = ( x & s ) > 0;
    int ry = ( y & s ) > 0;

    if (state == 0) {
      // # *--2  | 0  ->  *--2   | 1 -> 0  3   | 2 ->    2   |
      // #    |  |           |   |      |  |   |       /     |
      // # 0--1  |        0--1   |      1--2   |      1--0   |

      // # if x on right region, add lower left triangle (region 0)
      // #      (s * (s + 1) / 2) * rx
      // # if y on upper region, add lower right square as well (both regions 0 and 1)
      // #     (s * s) * ry
      d += (s * (s + 1) / 2) * rx + (s * s) * ry;

      // # change the state
      // #  rx  ry | (rx + ry)
      // #  0   0  |  0
      // #  1   0  |  1
      // #  1   1  |  2
      state = rx + ry;
    }else if (state == 1) {
      // # Determine how many squares to add
      // # equals number in s-by-s square times it's order in the curve
      // #  rx  ry | (3 * rx) ^ (1 - ry)
      // #  0   1  |  0 ^ 0 = [00] ^ [00] = 00 = 0
      // #  0   0  |  0 ^ 1 = [00] ^ [01] = 01 = 1
      // #  1   0  |  3 ^ 1 = [11] ^ [01] = 10 = 2
      // #  1   1  |  3 ^ 0 = [11] ^ [00] = 11 = 3
      d += s * s * ((3 * rx) ^ (1 - ry));
      //**********************************************************************80
      // # ROTATE
      // 0  3         0--1  14-15     Only rotate and/or flip if in the upper y 
      // |  |            |  |         quadrant (ry == 1).
      // 1--2   -->   3--2  13-12     
      //              |        |      Reflect vertically and horizontally BEFORE 
      //              4  7--8  11     swapping x and y only for the upper left 
      //              |  |  |  |      side (rx == 0 and ry == 1)
      //              5--6  9--10
      //
      // # 0  3  | 0  ->  0--1   | 1,2 -> 0  3   | 3 -> 2--3   |
      // # |  |  |           |   |        |  |   |      |      |
      // # 1--2  |        3--2   |        1--2   |      1--0   |
      //
      rot(n, x, y, rx, ry); // FIXME rot(n, &x, &y, rx, ry);
    }else if (state == 2) {
      // #    2  | 0  ->  2--1   | 1 ->    2   | 3 ->    2   |
      // #  /    |        |  |   |       /     |         |   |
      // # 1--0  |        3  0   |      1--0   |      0--1   |
      d += (s * s) * (rx == ry) + (s * (s + 1) / 2) * (rx == 1 && ry == 1);

      // #  rx  ry |  Target | state - (rx + ry)
      // #_________|_________|__________________
      // #  1   0  |  1      | 2 - (1 + 0) = 1
      // #  0   0  |  2      | 2 - (0 + 0) = 2
      // #  1   1  |  0      | 2 - (1 + 1) = 0

      // # new_state = current_state - (rx + ry)
      state = 2 - (rx + ry);
      if (state == 1) {
        // # If the state goes from state-2 to state-1, then rotate the hilbert
        // # curve 180 degrees (i.e. reflect horizonally and vertically)
        x = n-1 - x; 
        y = n-1 - y; 
      }
    }
  }

  const   std::vector<uint64_t> v(1, d);
  const size_t len = v.size();

  // storage vehicle we return the value to R  
  Rcpp::NumericVector nn(len);   

  // transfers values 'keeping bits' but changing type
  // using reinterpret_cast would get us a warning
  std::memcpy(&(nn[0]), &(v[0]), len * sizeof(uint64_t));

  // Make the return value compatible with the bit64 R package
  nn.attr("class") = "integer64";
  return nn;
}
```
````